# About visibility to grandchild class

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
package pack1;

public class Father {
    public String met1(){
        return "c ";
    }
    protected String met2(){
        return "b "+met1();
    }
}




package pack2;
import pack1.Father;

class Child extends Father {
    public String met1(){
        return "a ";
    }
}

class GrandChild extends Child {
    public String met2(){
        return super.met2() + "z" ;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Father f = new GrandChild();
        System.out.println(f.met2()); // Compile error here
    }
}
```

When I call `met2()`, it executes the version implemented in `GrandChild`, that calls to `super.met2()`, so it executed the version implemented in Child (that is the Father's version, because Child doesn't implements `met2()`). But why does the compiler say "`met2()` is not visible" if I'm calling it from GrandChild (subclass of Father, indirectly), when `met2()` is "protected"? It should recognise `met2()` because I'm calling it from a subclass and its protected (visible to subclasses)!!

Thank you!

Comment: are you talking about the access specifier for this guy --> `String met2()`?

Comment: The code above does not produce the error "met2() is not visible".

Comment: m2() in GrandChild  was default before, he edited and corrected the snippet

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573016/understanding-javas-protected-modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot weaken the privilege from the parent class. Since `met2()` from `Father` has `protected`, you can either override it with `protected` or with `public`.

Since you do not specify any privilege access, it defaults to `package protected`, which is a level weaker than `protected`.

This is the restriction from the language itself and follows the [Liskov substitution principle (LSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

**UPDATE**

If `Father` is in a different package than its "children", you will need to declare `met2()` as public in order to be able to access it from your subclasses

Comment: Ok, but when I change visibility from default to protected (or public), I keep getting the last error: "met2() is not visible". Why? I declared met2() "protected" in Father class, why it's not visible in GrandChild class?

Comment: @AlanCross - Can you please update the code in your question so that it corresponds to the error message that you say you're getting.

Comment: @AlanCross - That code appears to compile fine: https://ideone.com/uqgslj

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, @AlanCross, I've tested in my IDE, besides the `protected` part, I don't get anything related to `met2() is not visible`. Are you sure you are showing all the code?

Comment: Father class is in a package, Child and GrandChild are in another package. When i move Father class to the package of Child and GrandChild, the error dissapears. But I don't know why. I suposed "protected" allows visibility to subclasses (doesn't matter if they are in another package).

Comment: well, it does matter a lot if they are in different packages. If you did not specify "protected" in one of the methods, trying to call a method from one package to another won't work because, yes, you guessed it, "met2() is not visible". Can you make a realistic example with packages that can simulate what you are experiencing?

Comment: But, if i call met2() in Child class, compiler allows me to proceed. And Child and Father are in different packages. Why I can't do the same in GrandChild class?

Comment: it's not a problem in GrandChild either. You will get an error when you want to do in the your main method the `Father f = new GrandChild();` bit. `f.met2()` will fail because it has protected access. At least this is what I experienced. Can you tell us where is the exact line of code that you say the compiler/IDE is complaining about? Is it in your `main()` or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, it's included in main method. It's curious, because main is inside GrandChild class, but I'm sure that's the problem, doing it in main method. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you cannot reduce the visibility of the subclass methods when overriding.

since `m2()` in `Father` class is protected.
`m2()` in `GrandChild` class cannot have the default access specifier. It should be public or protected but not default as it results in lowering the visibility of the subclass.