# Protected members in Java

Tags: java

```
public SuperClass{
    protected int a1;
}

// Consider that two classes are in different package.
public SubClass extends SuperClass{
    void m1(){
        SuperClass sp = new SuperClass();
        sp.a1 = 1; // Error: Subclass.a1 is not visible
    }
}
```

I think that protected member a1 is visible to SubClass. In addition, field a1 belongs to SuperClass. So why it's not visible?

Comment: It's only visible in the subclass through an instance of the subclass type. You can't do `superClassObject.protectedMember`, it has to be `subclassObject.superclassProtectedmember` within the subclass.

Comment: but a1 belongs to SuperClass. So why a1 is not visible to sp object?

Comment: The answer on this question explains it best: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573016/understanding-javas-protected-modifier

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating a object of SuperClass. Then trying to access protected member of SuperClass. Evnethough it is inside SubClass, this is basically an instance trying to access protected member. Try this.a1 instead.